# Broadcom's BCM43227 freezes Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

I am running an Ubuntu 13.04 (fresh installation) in my laptop Acer Aspire 5750G. After being working some time, Ubuntu gets stuck, it freezes, and the only thing I can do is to switch off the laptop. I had the same problem with Ubuntu 12.04.

After several tests and having tried everything I could, I came up with the problem: the wireless card and its driver. I have a Broadcom BCM43227 and the driver I use is BCMWL. I suspect the problem comes from there, because when I am connected through a wired Ethernet connection, the laptop works perfectly. However, while working wireless, I always get frozen.

I went through all the installation instructions of BCM drivers I found in several forums, but nothing works for me. I mean, I have a wireless connection, I can connect to the Internet and everything goes as it should, but it suddenly gets stuck.

I hope someone could help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 drivers available for BCM43227 at the moment; one is bcmwl (provided by package bcmwl-kernel-source), and b43 (which is included in the kernel). According to b43's page, support of BCM43227 is 'WIP'.

You can try checking out and building the linux wireless repository (see wireless.kernel.org); their drivers are merged into the kernel with some delay, so you might get different results.

You can try reporting the error to Broadcom (don't expect much response on it, though, but it always worth a shot, if nothing else, to raise awareness), or add a miniature sized USB wireless controller that works under Ubuntu. Note, they stick out of the laptop by 6mm or so nowadays, they really are tiny.